# How can I declare and call a dynamic variable based on other hierarchical variables in Python?

Tags: python, list, outlook

I'm attempting  to write a scraper that will download  attachments  from an outlook account when I specify the path to folder to download from. I have  working code but the folder locations are hardcoded as below:-

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
namespace = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
root_folder = namespace.Folders.Item('Personal') #Inbox of interest
subfolder = root_folder.Folders['Inbox'].Folders['Holidays'].Folders['2009'].Folders['June'] #I have  Holidays,2009 and June folders in that hierarchical order in the  mailbox called Personal
Messages = subfolder.Items
```

With the code, I'm able to scrape emails and  attachments from that inbox  based on other preset parameters.

However, I'm interested in doing  this  dynamically, such that depending on the number of nested folders, I'll be  able  to build  up the **subfolder** variable as in the above code. I've tried  this using the below code.

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
namespace = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")            

root_mailbox  = str(input("Please Enter the Root folder name for the mailbox to scrape from:")) #Mailbox  to download from i.e. may be like "Personal" above.
if (root_mailbox == ""):
    print("You cannot leave this empty. Please insert the root folder name.")
else:
    
    root_folder = namespace.Folders.Item(root_mailbox) 
    sub_folders_num = int(input('How  many subfolders  are to be iterated on in the mailbox. Remember this has to be a number.')) #Specify the number of folders

    foldernames = [] #List to append to names values
    for i in range(1,sub_folders_num+1): 
        i = input("Input folder name(s) starting  with the one closest to the root folder") 
        foldernames.append(i)      
                

subfolder = root_folder.Folders[foldernames[0]].Folders[foldernames[1]].Folders[foldernames[2]] # Subfolder path but still "manually" specified 
Messages = subfolder.Items
```

**subfolder** variable  will be valid but  the process is  still manual. How can I be able to have  "Folders" specified dynamically based on sub_folders_num and  the  subfolder path built with the  list values as captured in the  loop?  This  will help in creating a more dynamic  scraper where I can download emails/attachments from any inbox folder path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as a [reduction](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) over `foldernames` using `getattr` to dynamically get the next attribute.

```
from functools import reduce


subfolder = reduce(lambda x, y: getattr(x, x.Folders[y]), foldernames, root_folder)
```

Alternatively, a non-functional approach that is less elegant, but easier to debug:

```
subfolder = root_folder
for folder_name in foldernames:
    subfolder = subfolder.Folders[folder_name]
```

The end result should be the same as the `reduce` method.

Comment: Thank you @Will for the response. I tried the code but  end  up with this  error. AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Folders' . Not  sure why as 'Folders' is a property of  the name space.

Comment: @Hummer I added an alternative approach that you may finder easier to debug. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you @Will  Da Silva for the  second  part. Definitely much easier to understand  and yes, it works very well.

Comment: I wrote  before fully testing the solution @Will.  Very small problem it  has  is that I'm able  to download all  attachments in all those folders specified and meet the set criteria. However, I'm only interested  in the attachments in the Last folder to be specified in the hierarchy.

Comment: Such a path `` subfolder = root_folder.Folders['Inbox'].Folders['Version2'].Folders['06. June'].Folders['14 June'] `` will only download  attachments in the folder 14 June.  The  above  code will download attachments in all these folders. Hope this makes  it a bit clear  @Will.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to iterate over all folders in Outlook recursively. Here is a sample VBA macro, so you may see the sequence of property and methods calls to get the job done:

```
private void EnumerateFoldersInDefaultStore()
{
    Outlook.Folder root =
        Application.Session.
        DefaultStore.GetRootFolder() as Outlook.Folder;
    EnumerateFolders(root);
}

// Uses recursion to enumerate Outlook subfolders.
private void EnumerateFolders(Outlook.Folder folder)
{
    Outlook.Folders childFolders = folder.Folders;
    if (childFolders.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (Outlook.Folder childFolder in childFolders)
        {
            // Write the folder path.
            Debug.WriteLine(childFolder.FolderPath);
            // Call EnumerateFolders using childFolder.
            EnumerateFolders(childFolder);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Eugene for the comment. I'll try follow your  the logic  and  implement  it in Python.